# Login with php return string with AsyncTask in android

Tags: java, php, android, http, android-asynctask

I'm developing an android application first time and don't have much knoweledge of java,

I've created a login screen & Integrated with Parse notification.

Now I wan't to check their username & password before sending registration to parse api.

I want to create asynctask so I can send http request during onclicklistener,

I want to fetch http response, that will be only true or false & further function will be on that condition.

E.g.
I've inputted username & password and app will send request to my php page,
page will only echo true if username & password is correct & false if they're wrong.

and if true next process will continue & on false, it will just toast about wrong username & password. Is there any quick code to make this happen?

Comment: You can check out AsyncTask which allows you to post data to your server and receive its response in a callback and then proceed to do what ever you need to. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Answer (score 0):

Minor quibble: it's that you are sending the request from onClickListener...

you probably want async tasks ( there is no quick code in java, the easy stuff is long, and the elegant stuff is abstract =] )

So, with that in mind:
this guy is great!
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html
the official( informative ) source
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

and here is an AsyncTask I wrote if you want a template; obviously, you'd be doing your basic httprequest instead of using the client I wrote and not updating a spinner &&, but when you get the response, you return it, just like I do( I'm using a class I defined that matches the JSON coming back from the API ); note that you can access variables in the containing class in doInBackgroud, and access the UI in onPostExecute, because of that former point, this all should not be *in* the listener, but called from the listener in the typical way: new GetPlaces().execute();

```
private class GetPlaces extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Places> {

    @Override
    protected Places doInBackground( Void[] p1 ) {
        GoogleClient client = new GoogleClient( );
        try {
            return client.executePlacesSearchGet(
                URLEncoder.encode( editFilter.getText( ).toString( ), "UTF-8" ), 
                getString( R.string.places_api_key ),
                Utils.latStringFromLocation( location ) + "," + Utils.lngStringFromLocation( location ), 
                50 );
        } catch(UnsupportedEncodingException e) {return null;}
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute( Places result ) {
        if( result != null ) {
            super.onPostExecute( result );
            places.clear( );
            places.addAll( result.results );
            placesSpinnerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged( );
            placesSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener( new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener( ){

                    public void onItemSelected( AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id ) {
                        AddAnchor.this.spinnerItemSelected( places.get( position ) );
                    }

                    public void onNothingSelected( AdapterView<?> p1 ) {
                    }
                } );
            placesSpinner.performClick( );

        } else Log.e( "TAG", "empty response!" );
    }

}
```

if you want to put int some data, you can make a constructor and feild in the class
e.g. new GetPlaces("username", "password").execute();

and the Async class would then have

```
private class GetPlaces extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Places> {
    String un;
    String pwd;
    public void GetPlaces(String un, String pwd){
        this.un = un;
        this.pwd = pwd;
    }

    @Override
    protected Places doInBackground( Void[] p1 ) {
            HttpRequestBLABLA.create(un) //or whatever, you have this code =]
            }
    }
```

gl hf!